# zero index for all rows in python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have problem with indexing python `dataframe`. I have dataframe which I fill it with loop. I simplified it like this :

```
d = pd.DataFrame(columns=['img', 'time', 'key'])
for i in range(5):
    image = i
    timepoint = i+1
    key = i+2
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'img':[image], 'timepoint':[timepoint], 'key': [key]})
    d = pd.concat([d, temp])
```

The problem is since it shows `0` as and index for all rows, I can not access to the specific row based on `.loc[]`. Does anybody have any idea how can I fix the problem and get normal index column?

Answer (score 10):

You may want to use the `ignore_index` parameter in your concatenation :

```
d = pd.concat([d, temp], ignore_index=True)
```

This gives me the following result :

```
   img  key time  timepoint
0  0.0  2.0  NaN        1.0
1  1.0  3.0  NaN        2.0
2  2.0  4.0  NaN        3.0
3  3.0  5.0  NaN        4.0
4  4.0  6.0  NaN        5.0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
d = d.reset_index(drop=True)
```

PS: It's better practice to make a list of rows and then turn it into a DataFrame, much less computationally expensive and it will make a good index instantly.

This list could be a list of lists combined with the columns in your DataFrame init or a list of dictionaries with column names as keys. In your case:

```
list_of_dicts = []
for i in range(5):
    new_row = {'img': i, 'time': i+1, 'key': i+2}
    list_of_dicts.append(new_row)
d = pd.DataFrame(new_row)
```

Comment: Actually, I'm searching for better way to create dataframe but I don't know what do you mean by make list of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think better is first fill `lists` by values and then once use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
image, timepoint, key = [],[],[]
for i in range(5):
    image.append(i)
    timepoint.append(i+1)
    key.append(i+2)

d = pd.DataFrame({'img':image, 'time':timepoint, 'key': key})
print (d)
   img  key  time
0    0    2     1
1    1    3     2
2    2    4     3
3    3    5     4
4    4    6     5
```